# Variable pack in C++

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic

There is already parameter pack in C++, can i declare a variable pack based on the parameter pack?

E.g.,

```
template<typename... Args>
bool all(Args... args)
{
    // Is the following definition of member_a possible?
    auto const & member_a = args.a; ... 
    return (... (member_a.isValidState() && member_a.isStateStable())); 
}
```

**EDIT**

Or a little bit more complex,

```
template<typename... Args>
bool all(Args... args)
{
    // function returnCurrentOrLast can be expensive, so it's 
    // desired to call it once.
    auto const & a = args.returnCurrentOrLast(true); ... 
    return (... (a.isValidState() && a.isStateStable())); 
}
```

Comment: Do you really need `member_a`?  Why not just `args.a.isValidState() ...` ect?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [pack expansion in lambda init-capture](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0780r2.html) to do this.

```
#include <utility>

template<typename... Args>
bool all(Args... args) {
  return [&...member_a = std::as_const(args.a)] {
    return (... && (member_a.isValidState() && member_a.isStateStable())); 
  }();
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/xMP511jdY)

Comment: Does this still work for the edited part of the post?

Comment: Yes, If `returnCurrentOrLast(true)` returns a reference, you can just change `args.a` to `args.returnCurrentOrLast(true)` in lambda init-capture list.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is there a reason using `return (... && (member_a.isValidState() && member_a.isStateStable()));` instead of `return ((member_a.isValidState() && member_a.isStateStable()) && ...);`? (Would it make a difference?

Comment: Yes @Scheff'sCat. It's explained in here [`fold expressions`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) #1 and #2

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tuple to store them, but in your example you could just access `isValidState` and `isStableState` directly on `args`.

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Args>
bool all(Args... args)
{
    auto tuple_members = std::make_tuple(args.a...); // This works, but why?
    return (... && (args.a.isValidState() && args.a.isStateStable())); 
}
```

Comment: How will use `tuple_members `? And does this still work for the edited part of the post?

Comment: Depends. If calling `returnCurrentOrLast` is cheap you can just chain it on in the expression. If you want to avoid calling it twice you can use the answer below, or the tuple appeoach I showed here in combination with `std::apply`.

Comment: You mean the answer by @康桓瑋？

Comment: The `&` is a typo. If you want to avoid copies you can go with `std::tie` instead. But that detail seems to be outside the scope of the question as the function itself takes arguments by value in the first place.